# Is there an algorithm by which you can remove cells in Sudoku?

Tags: java, sudoku

I'm trying to make a sudoku generator. I have to remove some cells from sudoku field, but I can't remove more than 30 cells. I wrote an algorithm that removes random cell (if without this cell sudoku still has one solution). How to delete 40 or 50 cells from sudoku?

```
        createBaseField();
        mixField(15);
        int min = 0;
        int max = 8;
        GameModes.chooseMode(MODE);
        int freeCells = new GameModes().getFreeCells();

        for (int k = 0; k <= freeCells; ) {
            int i = randomI(min, max);
            int j = randomJ(min, max);
            if (field[i][j] == 0) {
                i = randomI(min, max);
                j = randomJ(min, max);
            }

            int temp = field[i][j];
            field[i][j] = 0;

            if (solver.isOneSolution(field)) {
                k++;
                field[i][j] = 0;
            }
            if (!solver.isOneSolution(field)) {
                field[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (field[i][j] == 0) {` should be `while (field[i][j] == 0) {`

Comment: Backtracking.  When you remove a random cell that leads to a non-unique solution, put the cell back and pick another random cell.  You'll have to put some logic in to prevent an infinite loop, say after 20 tries with a non-unique solution, you stop.